# Find ODE which represents a given family of curves

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let the family of curves
$$y=\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n,$$

with $n\ne 0$. I want to kwnok the ODE from wich this family is the solution to. I have the followin ODE:

$$y'=\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n-1}$$

but the problem is to find an expression to $n$ wich depends only on $x$ and $y$. Any hint will be appreciated

Comment: What is the problem with $y' = f(x, n)$? You problem intrinsically depend on $n$...

Comment: It should be $ny'=\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n-1}$

Answer (score 1):

Starting from:$$y=\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n, y'=\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n-1}.$$

you get:

$$y' = \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n-1} = \left[\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\right]^\frac{n-1}{n} = y^{\frac{n-1}{n}}.$$

Now, notice that:

$$\log(y') = \log\left(y^{\frac{n-1}{n}}\right) \Rightarrow \log(y') = \frac{n-1}{n}\log\left(y\right) \Rightarrow \\
\Rightarrow n \log(y')-n\log(y) = -\log(y) \Rightarrow \\
\Rightarrow n = \frac{\log(y)}{\log(y)-\log(y')}.$$

The last equation expressess $n$ as a function of $y$ and $y'$.